# getting 400 error on webapi call blazorserver

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor, blazor-server-side

i am trying to setup a blazor server app, calling a webapi.
I keep getting a 400 error returned, when I call the API.

I have 3 Projects, projectserver and projectapi. projectserver is where the Blazor app sits and Project API is where the API sits.

I don't know if the apicall can find the API as it does not hit any breakpoints in the API section, I am totally confused, as if it cannot find the API then it should return a 404 or other error and not 400 ?

thank you for  your efforts.
this is my code,

Projectserver, this is where I post the Register Model to the API

```
    public string message { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel r = new RegisterModel();

    private async Task Create(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
        var client = clientfactory.CreateClient("ServerApi");
        var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/Account/Register",json); // check the Startup file and check base address for the Full route. 

        message = result.StatusCode.ToString();
    }
}
```

the ClientFactory returns the base address of what is defined in startup.cs

`services.AddHttpClient("ServerApi", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44302/"));`

the API is Projectserver and defined as follows.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountContoller : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly SecurityOptions _securityOptions;

        private readonly JwtIssuerOptions _jwtOptions;
        // GET: api/<Account>
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<Account>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<Account>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }
        // POST api/<Account>
        [HttpPost("Register")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<RegisterResult>> Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            RegisterResult r = new RegisterResult();

            var Exisits = await _context.Users.Where(r => r.EmailAddress == model.Email).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if(Exisits != null)
            {
                r.Sucsess = false;
                r.ErrorMessage = "Email - Already Exisits";
                return r;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    User newuser = new User();
                    newuser.CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    newuser.UserID = Guid.NewGuid();
                    newuser.MobileNumber = model.MobileNumber;
                    newuser.Password = model.Password;
                    newuser.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                    newuser.Surname = model.LastName;
                    _context.Users.Add(newuser);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    r.Sucsess = true;
                    return r;


                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    r.Sucsess = false;
                    r.ErrorMessage = e.ToString();
                    return r; 
                }
                
                

            }

            
        }
```

the Model classes are defined as Serializable

```
 [Serializable]
    public class RegisterResult
    {
        public bool Sucsess { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class RegisterModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string RoleID { get; set; }
        public string EntityID { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: could your check you post in the debug console. I suspect your sending two slashes.
try: var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("Account/Register",json);

Answer (score 0):

Can you please modify your code as below and give it a try:-

```
var serializedBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r);
var jsonRequestBodyContent = new StringContent(serializedBody, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
 var client = clientfactory.CreateClient("ServerApi");
 var result = await client.PostAsync("/Account/Register",jsonRequestBodyContent);
```